# vscode snippet transform file name regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, regexp-replace, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to transform `file-name.dto.ts` to `FileName` in a snippet.

`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.*)([^.*]).*/${1:/pascalcase}$2/}`

However, I'm not quite sure how to transform the second capture group or third.

If we don't wrap with a parenthesis, does it mean we don't capture?

```
  export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)([^.]*).*/${1:/upcase}$2/}Input {$2},
  export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.*).*/${1:/pascalcase}$2/}Output {},
```

Comment: I am not clear on what output you want on the `Output` line?  The same thing, just `export class FileNameOutput {}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first line (the Input line), try this:

`"export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^([^-]*)-([^.]*).*/${1:/pascalcase}${2:/pascalcase}/}Input {$2},"`

1. `${TM_FILENAME_BASE}` alone gets you to`file-name.dto`
2. Capture group 1 `^([^-]*)` gets you the part before the first `-`
3. Match the `-` but you will ignore it in the output so it doesn't need to be in a capture group.
4. Capture group 2 `([^.]*)` after the `-` until the first `.`
5. The rest `.*` will match `.dto` which again will be ignored so it doesn't need to be a capture group, but must be matched - you will effectively replace it with nothing.

Replacing with the transform:  `${1:/pascalcase}${2:/pascalcase}` so the first letter of both capture groups will be capitalized, the rest lower case.

On the `Output` line, if you are looking for this result:

`export class FileNameOutput {}`

use

`"export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^([^-]*)-([^.]*).*/${1:/pascalcase}${2:/pascalcase}/}Output {},"`

---

Just in case you don't realize it, in your code:

`export class ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/^(.)([^.]*).*/${1:/upcase}$2/}Input {$2},`

that last `{$2}` is NOT referring to any capture group - it is outside any transform.  It is only referring to a tabstop - where your cursor will go.  Let me know if it is your intention that that final `{$2}` actually be a transformed capture group.

Comment: Thank you so much. I now completely understood how it is working :)